# Python framework Kivy didn't notice the file with extension .kv

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem with Kivy framework. I defined parent and child classes in file main.py. Also I defined child class in file my.kv and added to him two widgets (Label and Button)

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 

class MyApp(App):
    pass

class Child(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Parent(BoxLayout):

    obj = ObjectProperty(Child())

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
Parent:

<Child>:
    Label:
        text: "Some text"
    Button:
        text: "Button"
```

I defined child class as property for parent class and during initialization I added it to parent class. But after starting the program I don't see previosly added widgets (Label and Button). I see on display just empty widget. As if file my.kv are simply ignored. Tell me please, what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line:

```
obj = ObjectProperty(Child())
```

is evaluated before the `my.kv` file is loaded, so at that point there is no rule to add a `Label` and a `Button` to the `Child` instance. That results in a `Child` instance that is an empty `BoxLayout`. When the `MyApp` starts, it then loads the `my.kv` file, and creates the `Parent` instance as the root widget. It also loads the `<Child>` rule, but that has no effect on the already created `Child` instance that is stored in the `obj` property.

This can be fixed in many different ways. One is to not create the `Child` instance until after the `my.kv` file is loaded. Like this:

```
class Parent(BoxLayout):

    obj = ObjectProperty(None)   # initialize the obj to None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # create the Child instance now
        self.obj = Child()

        self.add_widget(self.obj)
```

Another way is to just include the `Child` as a child of `Parent` in the `my.kv` file.

Or you could put the `<Child>` rule in a separate `kv` file/string, and load that in your `.py` file after the definition of `Child`, but before the definition of `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your main python file and your kivy file should be same.

If you name your python file 'app.py' and name your kivy file 'kivy.kv' your python file won't find the kivy file.

But, if you name both of the file name same like 'app.py' and 'app.kv' the python file will recognize the kivy file and execute as expected.

Comment: Application class named 'MyApp' and kivy language file named my.kv. It's mean that my.kv have to start automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to Johns answer: if you want to use kv lang ids or anything like that particularly, you can use on_kv_post

for instance, if you had a kv:

```
Parent:
    Child:
        id: child
```

you could assign that to your parent property by id:

```
class Parent(BoxLayout):

    obj = ObjectProperty() 

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Parent,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_kv_post(self,Parent):
        self.obj = self.ids.child
```

this event is useful for running code or triggering other functions when the kv of the widget has loaded.

Answer (score -1):

It happens sometimes, try to load it manually:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
...
class MyApp(App):
...
    def build(self):
        with open('my.kv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as kvfile:
            Builder.load_string(kvfile.read())
```

P.S.: do you really need to inherit BoxLayout several times?

Comment: Yes. I need it.

Comment: Well, maybe it's something wrong in the kv file. Show the app class and kv file.